# How to call method in route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have two forms of search

```
POST /search
GET  /search?q=q
```

For POST, I can just use `Meteor.call` in client.

```
'submit form': function() {
    Meteor.call('search', data......
}
```

For GET, How can I call `Meteor.call` in router?

```
Router.route('/search', {
  template: 'ItemList',
  data: function() {
  return Meteor.call('search', this.params.query); // ???
}
```

and about the `search` method, it will not only search database but also search file system.

I don't know how to do the second GET search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not doing the calls in your router.  The router is responsible for directing the flow of actions and it would make it more complex if it was also managing all of the data and external resource tracking.

In the template level, you could easily detect the routers params (Router.current()) or have them passed directly from the router in the data section.

Then on rendered you could have the template hit your call function.  And then make it reactive with some dependency tracking

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Router.current().params.q` to get the q variable from url.

You won't need data: function() in the said approach.